They would not rest until they had exacted revenge

They would not rest until they had exacted revenge.

What's the meaning of 'would' here? inclination/tendency in the past?
Is this sentence equal to: Not until they had exacted revenge did they rest.

Where did you see the sentence? It's going to depend on whether the passage is in the past or present tense, and other factors.

In a dictionary. I think the tense is not a problem here because the past perfect(pluperfect) in the 'until clause' means past situation.

Dictionary examples are removed from their context and therefore sometimes their exact meaning just can't be known. Though in this case JavaLatte's answer seems reasonable.

If you talk about a current situation, you say

They will not rest until they have exacted revenge

In this sentence, will indicates that the current situation will continue into the future. will simply indicates the future.
If  you describe the same situation that occurred in the past, you change the tense backwards:

They would not rest until they had exacted revenge

In this sentence, would indicates that the past situation you are describing will continue into the future relative to that past situation.

Is this sentence equal to: Not until they had exacted revenge did they rest. ?

@gomadeng It expresses past intention; it doesn't say whether they exacted revenge. So the answer to that question is No, your sentence is not the same.
